# How to return columns that don't have a specific string - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, left-join

I need to find the name and date of birth of all passengers that have not booked flights with Qantas.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT BOOKING.name, BOOKING.DOB
FROM BOOKING 
LEFT JOIN FLIGHT ON BOOKING.flightNumber = FLIGHT.flightNumber
WHERE NOT FLIGHT.name = 'Qantas';
```

Here is the result I am receiving:

```
name      DOB
Douglas   1967-11-20
Ben       1994-04-22
Jean      1988-05-12
Alex      1992-07-21
Duke      1974-03-28
```

Here is the output I should be receiving:

```
name      DOB
Jean      1988-05-12
Alex      1992-07-21
Duke      1974-03-28
```

HERE IS THE FIDDLE: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dE8JiHq3UDhaWWkH7u1vCS/0

Here is the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE BOOKING (
name            VARCHAR(30),        /* Passenger's name*/
DOB             DATE,               /* Passenger's DOB */
flightNumber    CHAR(6),            /* Flight number */
departAirport   VARCHAR(50),        /* Departure airport */
departTime      DATETIME,           /* Departure date and time */
class           CHAR(10),           /* class of the seat */
bookingTime     DATETIME    NOT NULL,   /* Booking time */
CONSTRAINT BOOKING_PK PRIMARY KEY(name, DOB, flightNumber, departAirport, departTime, class, bookingTime),
CONSTRAINT BOOKING_FK1 FOREIGN KEY(name, DOB) REFERENCES PASSENGER(name, DOB),
CONSTRAINT BOOKING_FK2 FOREIGN KEY(flightNumber, departAirport, departTime, class) REFERENCES SEATING(flightNumber, departAirport, departTime, class));

CREATE TABLE FLIGHT (
name            VARCHAR(30),            /* airline name */
flightNumber    CHAR(6),                /* Flight number */
departAirport   VARCHAR(50),            /* Departure airport */
departTime      DATETIME    NOT NULL,   /* Departure date and time */
arriveAirport   VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,   /* Arriving airport */
arriveTime      DATETIME,               /* Arriving date and time */
capacity        DECIMAL(3)  NOT NULL,   /* Capacity for passengers */
airliner        VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,   /* Aircraft for passengers */
CONSTRAINT FLIGHT_PK PRIMARY KEY(flightNumber, departAirport, departTime),
CONSTRAINT FLIGHT_CK1 UNIQUE (flightNumber, arriveAirport, arriveTime),
CONSTRAINT FLIGHT_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (name) REFERENCES AIRLINE(name));


INSERT INTO BOOKING VALUES ('Mike', STR_TO_DATE('10/08/1982', '%d/%m/%Y'), 'QF8764', 'SYD', STR_TO_DATE('10/05/2019 08:45', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 'ECONOMY', STR_TO_DATE('1/05/2019 10:35', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'));
INSERT INTO BOOKING VALUES ('Mike', STR_TO_DATE('10/08/1982', '%d/%m/%Y'), 'QF322', 'AKL', STR_TO_DATE('18/05/2019 06:00', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 'ECONOMY', STR_TO_DATE('1/05/2019 10:35', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'));
INSERT INTO BOOKING VALUES ('Jean', STR_TO_DATE('12/05/1988', '%d/%m/%Y'), 'JQ402', 'SYD', STR_TO_DATE('23/04/2019 07:05', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 'ECONOMY', STR_TO_DATE('1/04/2019 12:05', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'));
INSERT INTO BOOKING VALUES ('Alex', STR_TO_DATE('21/07/1992', '%d/%m/%Y'), 'VA505', 'SYD', STR_TO_DATE('24/04/2019 07:10', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 'BUSINESS', STR_TO_DATE('10/04/2019 09:35', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'));
INSERT INTO BOOKING VALUES ('Alex', STR_TO_DATE('21/07/1992', '%d/%m/%Y'), 'VA523', 'SYD', STR_TO_DATE('26/04/2019 13:10', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 'BUSINESS', STR_TO_DATE('10/04/2019 09:35', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'));
INSERT INTO BOOKING VALUES ('Ben', STR_TO_DATE('22/04/1994', '%d/%m/%Y'), 'QF8764', 'SYD', STR_TO_DATE('10/05/2019 08:45', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 'ECONOMY', STR_TO_DATE('25/04/2019 11:35', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'));
INSERT INTO BOOKING VALUES ('Ben', STR_TO_DATE('22/04/1994', '%d/%m/%Y'), 'QF322', 'AKL', STR_TO_DATE('18/05/2019 06:00', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 'ECONOMY', STR_TO_DATE('27/04/2019 16:15', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'));
INSERT INTO BOOKING VALUES ('Ben', STR_TO_DATE('22/04/1994', '%d/%m/%Y'), 'JQ402', 'SYD', STR_TO_DATE('23/04/2019 07:05', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 'ECONOMY', STR_TO_DATE('17/04/2019 14:30', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'));
INSERT INTO BOOKING VALUES ('Duke', STR_TO_DATE('28/03/1974', '%d/%m/%Y'), 'VA505', 'SYD', STR_TO_DATE('24/04/2019 07:10', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 'BUSINESS', STR_TO_DATE('20/04/2019 13:30', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'));
INSERT INTO BOOKING VALUES ('Josef', STR_TO_DATE('27/11/1982', '%d/%m/%Y'), 'QF401', 'SYD', STR_TO_DATE('05/05/2019 06:05', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 'ECONOMY', STR_TO_DATE('22/04/2019 10:30', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'));
INSERT INTO BOOKING VALUES ('Harry', STR_TO_DATE('16/07/1990', '%d/%m/%Y'), 'QF860', 'SYD', STR_TO_DATE('23/04/2019 07:10', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 'FIRST', STR_TO_DATE('21/04/2019 10:30', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'));
INSERT INTO BOOKING VALUES ('Will', STR_TO_DATE('20/10/1977', '%d/%m/%Y'), 'QF8764', 'SYD', STR_TO_DATE('10/05/2019 08:45', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 'BUSINESS', STR_TO_DATE('25/04/2019 15:30', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'));
INSERT INTO BOOKING VALUES ('Douglas', STR_TO_DATE('20/11/1967', '%d/%m/%Y'), 'QF497', 'SYD', STR_TO_DATE('26/05/2019 22:05', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 'ECONOMY', STR_TO_DATE('21/04/2019 12:30', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'));
INSERT INTO BOOKING VALUES ('Douglas', STR_TO_DATE('20/11/1967', '%d/%m/%Y'), 'CA2842', 'PEK', STR_TO_DATE('10/05/2019 22:05', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 'ECONOMY', STR_TO_DATE('21/04/2019 12:30', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'));

INSERT INTO FLIGHT VALUES ('Qantas', 'QF8764', 'SYD', STR_TO_DATE('10/05/2019 08:45', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 'AKL', STR_TO_DATE('10/05/2019 14:00', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 180, 'Boeing 737-900');
INSERT INTO FLIGHT VALUES ('Qantas', 'QF322', 'AKL', STR_TO_DATE('18/05/2019 06:00', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 'SYD', STR_TO_DATE('18/05/2019 07:40', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 215, 'Boeing 767-200');
INSERT INTO FLIGHT VALUES ('Qantas', 'QF140', 'AKL', STR_TO_DATE('18/05/2019 06:30', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 'SYD', STR_TO_DATE('18/05/2019 08:10', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 260, 'Boeing 777-200');
INSERT INTO FLIGHT VALUES ('Jetstar', 'JQ402', 'SYD', STR_TO_DATE('23/04/2019 07:05', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 'OOL', STR_TO_DATE('23/04/2019 07:25', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 177, 'Boeing 737-900');
INSERT INTO FLIGHT VALUES ('Qantas', 'QF860', 'SYD', STR_TO_DATE('23/04/2019 07:10', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 'OOL', STR_TO_DATE('23/04/2019 07:35', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 185, 'Boeing 737-900');
INSERT INTO FLIGHT VALUES ('Virgin Australia', 'VA505', 'SYD', STR_TO_DATE('24/04/2019 07:10', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 'OOL', STR_TO_DATE('24/04/2019 07:30', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 240, 'Boeing 777-200');
INSERT INTO FLIGHT VALUES ('Jetstar', 'JQ404', 'SYD', STR_TO_DATE('26/04/2019 08:50', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 'OOL', STR_TO_DATE('26/04/2019 09:10', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 240, 'Boeing 777-200');
INSERT INTO FLIGHT VALUES ('Qantas', 'QF862', 'SYD', STR_TO_DATE('18/05/2019 11:45', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 'OOL', STR_TO_DATE('18/05/2019 12:10', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 180, 'Boeing 737-900');
INSERT INTO FLIGHT VALUES ('Jetstar', 'JQ404', 'SYD', STR_TO_DATE('26/04/2019 13:05', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 'OOL', STR_TO_DATE('26/04/2019 13:25', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 250, 'Boeing 777-200');
INSERT INTO FLIGHT VALUES ('Virgin Australia', 'VA523', 'SYD', STR_TO_DATE('26/04/2019 13:10', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 'OOL', STR_TO_DATE('26/04/2019 13:30', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 180, 'Boeing 737-900');
INSERT INTO FLIGHT VALUES ('Virgin Australia', 'VA523', 'SYD', STR_TO_DATE('10/05/2019 15:10', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 'OOL', STR_TO_DATE('10/05/2019 15:30', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 182, 'Boeing 737-900');
INSERT INTO FLIGHT VALUES ('Virgin Australia', 'VA500', 'OOL', STR_TO_DATE('18/05/2019 06:00', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 'SYD', STR_TO_DATE('18/05/2019 08:30', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 185, 'Boeing 737-900');
INSERT INTO FLIGHT VALUES ('Jetstar', 'JQ401', 'OOL', STR_TO_DATE('18/05/2019 06:10', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 'SYD', STR_TO_DATE('18/05/2019 08:40', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 258, 'Boeing 777-200');
INSERT INTO FLIGHT VALUES ('Jetstar', 'JQ403', 'OOL', STR_TO_DATE('18/05/2019 07:55', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 'SYD', STR_TO_DATE('18/05/2019 10:25', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 232, 'Boeing 767-200');
INSERT INTO FLIGHT VALUES ('Jetstar', 'JQ409', 'OOL', STR_TO_DATE('18/05/2019 10:05', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 'SYD', STR_TO_DATE('18/05/2019 12:35', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 182, 'Boeing 737-900');
INSERT INTO FLIGHT VALUES ('Jetstar', 'JQ501', 'SYD', STR_TO_DATE('05/05/2019 06:05', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 'MEL', STR_TO_DATE('05/05/2019 07:35', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 271, 'Airbus A330');
INSERT INTO FLIGHT VALUES ('Qantas', 'QF401', 'SYD', STR_TO_DATE('05/05/2019 06:05', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 'MEL', STR_TO_DATE('05/05/2019 07:35', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 224, 'Boeing 777-200');
INSERT INTO FLIGHT VALUES ('Virgin Australia', 'VA808', 'SYD', STR_TO_DATE('05/05/2019 07:00', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 'MEL', STR_TO_DATE('05/05/2019 08:35', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 188, 'Boeing 737-900');
INSERT INTO FLIGHT VALUES ('Qantas', 'QF400', 'MEL', STR_TO_DATE('11/05/2019 06:00', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 'SYD', STR_TO_DATE('11/05/2019 07:25', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 303, 'Airbus A330');
INSERT INTO FLIGHT VALUES ('Qantas', 'QF408', 'MEL', STR_TO_DATE('11/05/2019 07:00', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 'SYD', STR_TO_DATE('11/05/2019 08:25', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 321, 'Boeing 747-8');
INSERT INTO FLIGHT VALUES ('Virgin Australia', 'VA815', 'MEL', STR_TO_DATE('11/05/2019 07:30', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 'SYD', STR_TO_DATE('11/05/2019 08:55', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 206, 'Airbus A350');
INSERT INTO FLIGHT VALUES ('Air China', 'CA3101', 'SYD', STR_TO_DATE('26/05/2019 22:15', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 'PEK', STR_TO_DATE('27/05/2019 10:55', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 760, 'Airbus A380');
INSERT INTO FLIGHT VALUES ('Qantas', 'QF129', 'SYD', STR_TO_DATE('26/05/2019 09:35', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 'PEK', STR_TO_DATE('26/05/2019 23:40', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 460, 'Boeing 747-8');
INSERT INTO FLIGHT VALUES ('Qantas', 'QF4014', 'PEK', STR_TO_DATE('10/05/2019 07:35', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 'SYD', STR_TO_DATE('11/05/2019 08:30', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 640, 'Airbus A380');
INSERT INTO FLIGHT VALUES ('Qantas', 'QF497', 'SYD', STR_TO_DATE('26/05/2019 22:05', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 'PEK', STR_TO_DATE('27/05/2019 23:40', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 780, 'Airbus A380');
INSERT INTO FLIGHT VALUES ('Air China', 'CA2842', 'PEK', STR_TO_DATE('10/05/2019 22:05', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 'SYD', STR_TO_DATE('11/05/2019 08:30', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 420, 'Boeing 747-8'); 
INSERT INTO FLIGHT VALUES ('Qantas', 'QF111', 'SYD', STR_TO_DATE('22/04/2019 18:20', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 'MEL', STR_TO_DATE('22/04/2019 19:10', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), 160, 'Boeing 737-900');
```

Comment: Please try replacing your left join with `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: If you access the fiddle, it'll show that `INNER JOIN` returns the same result

Comment: I have now added the sample data to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join the tables, group by booking and set the condition in the HAVING clause:

```
SELECT b.name, b.DOB
FROM BOOKING b LEFT JOIN FLIGHT f
ON b.flightNumber = f.flightNumber
GROUP BY b.name, b.DOB
HAVING SUM(f.name = 'Qantas') = 0;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dE8JiHq3UDhaWWkH7u1vCS/1).
Results:

```
| name | DOB        |
| ---- | ---------- |
| Alex | 1992-07-21 |
| Duke | 1974-03-28 |
| Jean | 1988-05-12 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a query

```
SELECT c.olumns_you
     , w.ant
  FROM table_a c
  LEFT
  JOIN table_b w
    ON w.something = c.something
   AND w.other_thing = 'needle'
 WHERE w.ant IS NULL
```

Comment: Honestly...it's not the worst beginner question I've seen here :-)

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT DISTINCT BOOKING.name, BOOKING.DOB
FROM BOOKING 
LEFT JOIN FLIGHT ON BOOKING.flightNumber = FLIGHT.flightNumber
WHERE  FLIGHT.name != 'Qantas';
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps.